# Create a empty tar file and then store its name in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a shell script in which a tar file with today's date and time will be created.

```
tar -zvcf "log_grabber$(date '+%y-%m-%d_%H%M').tar.gz" --files-from /dev/null
```

Now, to add more files to this tar files after running the find command. How can I get the name of the tar file and use it in the output of the find command?

```
find . -type f -name 'local*' -newermt "$user_date" -exec tar -rvf <variable tar file> {} \;
```

Any help will be very much useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
tar -zvcf "log_grabber$(date '+%y-%m-%d_%H%M').tar.gz" --files-from /dev/null
```

Create a variable with the name first and use that:

```
name="log_grabber$(date '+%y-%m-%d_%H%M').tar.gz"    
tar -zvcf "$name" --files-from /dev/null
```

And then:

```
find . -type f -name 'local*' -newermt "$user_date" -exec tar -rvf "$name" {} +
```

Note that I changed `\;` to `+` so that `tar` gets multiple files in one invocation, rather than one `tar` invocation per file.

Comment: Is there any way that we can do it directly, instead of storing it in the variables names? Just want to check.

Comment: @AkshitGupta Minutes may change between subsequent invocations of `date`, this is why it must be called once and the result stored in a variable for reuse. If you drop the date from the filename, then you can hard-code the filename instead of using a variable. Alternatively, create your `tar` archive in one `tar` invocation without subsequent updates.